# How do I generate dynamic page title in MVC project

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am developing my project in MVC and I want to generate dynamic page titles. My header, content and footer are split in 3 different view files. I want to generate the page title from the content view file and pass it to the model which will then be passed to the header view file. I tried different things and none of them worked. Here is my code:

**controller page.php**

```
class Page extends Controller
{

    public $pageTitle;

    public function setPageTitle($title)
    {
        $this->pageTitle = $title;
    }

    public function getPageTitle()
    {
        return $this->pageTitle;
    }

    /**
     * Open file from view/pages/ folder.
     * @param String
     */
    public function index($page = 'about')
    {
        if(!file_exists(ROOT.'/app/view/pages/'.$page.'.php'))
        {
            //redirect 404
        }
        $data['title'] = self::getPageTitle();

        $this->view('header', $data);
        $this->view('pages/'.$page);
        $this->view('footer');
    }

}
```

**view header.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title><?= $data['title'] ?></title>
</head>
<body>
```

**view about.php**

```
<?php
    $controller = new Page;
    $controller->setPageTitle('title of the page about us');
?>
content about us, contact form, etc.
```

$data is always returned NULL. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First, try
    `<title><?php echo $data['title']; ?></title>`
If that is not working, make sure that in the function `$this->view($arg, $arg2)` the second argument is used for getting the data, is able to take an array and named $data. If it's named other (like $arg2), you need to use `$arg2['title']` in your template heder.php.

Comment: It should be taking an array. Actually when I var_dump `$data` in **controller page.php**, it returns null  even there. But when I var_dump it in the `getPageTitle` method (which is in the same file), the value is as it should be. For some reason in the `index` method, `$pageTitle` is losing its value.

Comment: Are you calling `page.php -> index()` from inside `about.php` or from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

I don't about your Idea. But , you can simply do this just using two php files.

1. ) In `controller page.php` file , just type your Web Site name.
2. ) After that include this controller page.php which you want display your Site Name.

> controller page.php file

```
Web Site Name
```

> header.php file

```
<?php
include("controller page.php")
?>
```

or you can use this function in `controller page.php` file

```
<?php

function Sitename()
    {
    $title = "Wisdom University";
    return $title;
    }

echo Sitename();    

?>
```

Comment: This is not at all what I need. I need to pass a variable from `page.php` to `header.php` through the model.